# JavaScript set variable to certain value if key is down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm wondering how I can create something using JavaScript where a variable called x is set to -1 as a default. If the user is pressing any key on their keyboard, the variable will be set to -2. Once they let go of the key and no key is being pressed, the variable will revert back to -1.  How can this be done? I've already declared the variable using JavaScript:

```
let x = -1;
```

I'm not sure what to do next however. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use window events:

`window.onkeydown = () => {x = -2};`

`window.onkeyup = () => {x = -1}`